# Function call using single quotes vs no quotes

Tags: javascript, html

The following pieces of code uses the function setInterval() to continually update a 'clock'. The only difference is in the function call setInterval().

When I change the setInterval argument from

```
setInterval('updateTime()',1000);
```

to

```
setInterval(updateTime(),1000);
```

[from single to no quotes], it does not work. Can anyone explain this to me?

Single Quotes:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function updateTime(){
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            var now= h+':'+m+':'+s;
            document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = h+':'+m+':'+s;//set the text in 'timer' id below to the date
            setInterval('updateTime()', 1000); //////SEE THIS LINE//////
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id='timer'> Time </p>
    <script>
        updateTime();
    </script>
</body>
```

No Quotes:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function updateTime(){
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            var now= h+':'+m+':'+s;
            document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = h+':'+m+':'+s;//set the text in 'timer' id below to the date
            setInterval(updateTime(), 1000);//////SEE THIS LINE//////
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id='timer'> Time </p>
    <script>
        updateTime();
    </script>
</body>
```

Online js console for testing can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: fix your jsfiddle link ;)

Comment: Because with the second you are doing the function call right then, you are supposed to just pass a reference to the function when not using a string, i.e. just the name `setInterval(updateTime,`

Comment: Note: **The difference between `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` is very important.** Do *not* call `setInterval()` from within the function. Either use `setInterval(updateTime,1000)` *outside* the function, or use `setTimeout(updateTime,1000))` *inside* the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this
`setInterval(updateTime, 1000);` 
without ()

Now  coming to the question why.

The Setinterval function **evaluates** the content **if string** and **executes if function name**

To explain why it does **execute** the **updateTime()** with brackets **immediately** is because it tries to **execute the output of the updateTime function in interval loop**, that will be undefined if you are not returning anything and will be treated as function name if it returns a string. Anything else will be overlooked or error thrown.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 6):

```
 setInterval('updateTime()', 1000);
```

You are passing string to the setInterval as the first argument.You need to pass the function reference

Correct Way

```
setInterval(updateTime, 1000)
```

Comment: oh whoa, I didn't even notice you answered

Comment: additionally, in the second example OP is passing the returned value of a function instead of the function itself

Comment: You don't "need" to pass a function reference, the line you quote in your answer with the string works as is.

Comment: But why does the string also work?

Comment: Does js accept the fx by reference from string input as well?

Comment: @skim - You can pass a string of arbitrary JS code. `setInterval()` (or `setTimeout()`) will basically `eval()` that string at the specified interval. But although you *can* do this, you shouldn't. Best practice is to pass a function reference directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your second code to

```
setInterval(updateTime,1000);
```

it should work. The reason is because ^there you're passing a function pointer to set interval while in your answer updateTime() is passing the return value of updateTime to setInterval.